# How To Pass ErrorMessage From API to MVC In Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core-mvc

I've created an API. When you face an error, It shows you the type of error with it's message. But When I try to use that API in my MVC project, It just shows the type of error. I want to see the message in Modelstate.AddModelError

Here is API controller for Login

```
[HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoginUser([FromBody] UserDtoLogin user)
        {
            var userToRetrieve = await _applicationDbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == user.UserName);
            if (userToRetrieve == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("username", "Such a user doesn't exists! Enter the correct username please");
                return NotFound(ModelState);
            }
            if (!_userRepository.VerifyPasswordHash(user.Password, userToRetrieve.PasswordHash, userToRetrieve.PasswordSalt))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("password", "Wrong Password!");
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            await _userRepository.Login(userToRetrieve);
            return Ok(user);
        }
```

Here is MVC Controller for Login

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(User user)
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost:42045/api/user/login");
            if (user != null)
            {
                request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user),
                    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            }
            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                ViewBag.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
                var apiString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(apiString);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
            }
            return View(user);

        }
```

Comment: I don't think you can persist the modelstate. Return the error codes in the API and set the modelstate in the web app. Here's the return object for ObjectResult: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.notfoundobjectresult?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

I write a simple demo to show how to pass ErrorMessage From API to MVC In Asp.Net Core, you can reference to it.

**API**

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {

    //For testing convenience, I use hard code here

        List<UserDtoLogin> context = new List<UserDtoLogin>
        {
            new UserDtoLogin
            {
                UserName = "Mike"
            },

            new UserDtoLogin
            {
                UserName = "Jack"
            },

            new UserDtoLogin
            {
                UserName = "Lily"
            }
        };

        [HttpPost("login")]
        public IActionResult LoginUser([FromBody] UserDtoLogin user)
        {
            var userToRetrieve =  context.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == user.UserName);
            if (userToRetrieve == null)
            {
               
                return BadRequest("Such a user doesn't exists! Enter the correct username please");
            }

            //your logic.....

            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

**MVC/Controller**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Privacy(UserDtoLogin todoItem)
        {
            var todoItemJson = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(todoItem),Encoding.UTF8,Application.Json);

            using var httpResponseMessage = await _httpClient.PostAsync("your api url", todoItemJson);
            var errormessage = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            return View(todoItem);
        }
```

Then you can see it can receive the errormessage successfully.

[image]